# Ubuntu Apache2 development program

Tags: linux

I am running a website on a ubuntu server using apache2, php, mysql and so on. What I am looking for is if there is anything out there that can enable me to have one version of the website that i can develop on without disturbing the live version and when I am done i can just enable the new version to the live version of the website?

Comment: Ultimately the only sane choice is to install a local copy of Apache, PHP and MySql, deploy on your own computer and work there, completely isolate from the real server.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options you can use.

- You can have different virtual hosts in apache for development and production environments
- You can use git to store the development and production (master) version of the websites and use git to pull each of them, or git-push to send each version to its own environment
- You can use two folders for the different versions and using symlinks point each of the versions to its own site
- Many other options, including using tools such as Jenkins and Teamcity to deploy each of the versions to its own environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a different version of the webserver with almost identical configfiles. A server that listens on a different port. A port that is not open to the wider internet, perhaps port 8080. You can also set the "`Allow from`" Apache directive, perhaps "Allow from 123.45.67.89"
to restrict access from a single host on your intranet.